# Não consigo abrir modal (dialog)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Estava utilizando um template bootstrap, mas como era irregular (não haviam pago) a empresa comprou outro, também bootstrap.

Mas o jeito que montava o modal antes não funciona mais. Não consigo abrir o modal do template com os dados que preciso para edição.

***Pela foto, pode-se ver que tenho 2 botões que chamam o modal, o EDITAR do lado direito e embaixo do datatable outro.
Preciso clicar no EDITAR e carregar os dados conforme a foto, mas não é isso que acontece, quando eu clico no EDITAR nao abre nada, mas quando clico no "OPEN DIALOG" abre o modal e com as edições que preciso.***

Segue print: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu jsp:

```
            <!-- row Adicionar novas funcionalidades aqui-->
            <div class="row">   

                <!-- row -->
                <div class="row">

                    <!-- NEW WIDGET START -->
                    <article class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">

                        <!-- Widget ID (each widget will need unique ID)-->
                        <div class="jarviswidget jarviswidget-color-darken" id="wid-id-0" 
                        data-widget-editbutton="true"
                        data-widget-colorbutton="true"
                        data-widget-editbutton="true"
                        data-widget-togglebutton="true"
                        data-widget-deletebutton="true"
                        data-widget-fullscreenbutton="true"
                        data-widget-custombutton="true"
                        data-widget-collapsed="false"
                        data-widget-sortable="true">
                            <!-- widget options:
                            usage: <div class="jarviswidget" id="wid-id-0" data-widget-editbutton="false">

                            data-widget-colorbutton="false"
                            data-widget-editbutton="false"
                            data-widget-togglebutton="false"
                            data-widget-deletebutton="false"
                            data-widget-fullscreenbutton="false"
                            data-widget-custombutton="false"
                            data-widget-collapsed="true"
                            data-widget-sortable="false"

                            -->

                            <header>
                                <span class="widget-icon"> <i class="fa fa-table"></i> </span>
                                <h2>Standard Data Tables </h2>

                            </header>

                            <!-- widget div-->
                            <div>

                                <!-- widget edit box -->
                                <div class="jarviswidget-editbox">
                                    <!-- This area used as dropdown edit box -->

                                </div>
                                <!-- end widget edit box -->

                                <!-- widget content -->
                                <div class="widget-body no-padding">

                                    <table id="dt_basic" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" width="100%">
                                        <thead>                         
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Nome do Responsável</th>
                                                <th>Telefone Contato</th>
                                                <th>Celular</th>
                                                <th>E-mail</th>
                                                <th>Editar</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr ng-repeat="x in organizacoes">
                                                <td><span ng-bind="x.nomeResponsavel" /></td>
                                                <td><span ng-bind="x.telefone" /></td>
                                                <td><span ng-bind="x.celular" /></td>
                                                <td><span ng-bind="x.emailResponsavel" /></td>
                                                <td><button type="submit" id="dialog_link" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="setSelected(x);" />Editar</button></td>                                                   
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>

                                </div>
                                <!-- end widget content -->

                            </div>
                            <!-- end widget div -->

                        </div>
                        <!-- end widget -->             

            </div>
            <!-- end row -->

            <!-- INICIO DIALOG -->
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">                
                            <div class="well well-sm well-light">
                        <a href="#" id="dialog_link" class="btn btn-info"> Open Dialog </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  

            <!-- ui-dialog -->
            <div id="dialog_simple" title="Dialog Simple Title">
                <p>
                    <!-- START MODAL -->

                                    <form name="form" id="form_sample_2" role="form"
                                        class="form-horizontal ng-pristine ng-valid" novalidate>
                                        <div class="form-body">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label col-md-3">Nome:<span
                                                    class="required" aria-required="true"> * </span></label>
                                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                                    <input type="text"
                                                        ng-model="organizacoesSelecionada.nomeResponsavel"
                                                        class="form-control" id="nomeResponsavel" maxlength="100"
                                                        name="nomeResponsavel" required> <span
                                                        style="color: red"
                                                        ng-show="submitted && form.nomeResponsavel.$error.required">Campo
                                                        Nome Responsável Obrigatório.</span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label col-md-3">Telefone:<span
                                                    class="required" aria-required="true"> * </span></label>
                                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                                    <input type="text" ng-model="organizacoesSelecionada.telefone" 
                                                        mask="(11) 9999-9999"
                                                        class="form-control" id="telefone" maxlength="100"
                                                        name="telefone" required> <span style="color: red"
                                                        ng-show="submitted && form.telefone.$error.required">Campo
                                                        Telefone Obrigatório.</span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label col-md-3">Celular:<span
                                                    class="required" aria-required="true"> * </span></label>
                                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                                    <input type="text" ng-model="organizacoesSelecionada.celular"
                                                        mask="(99) 9?9999-9999"
                                                        class="form-control" id="celular" maxlength="100"
                                                        name="celular" required> <span style="color: red"
                                                        ng-show="submitted && form.celular.$error.required">Campo
                                                        Celular Obrigatório.</span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label col-md-3">E-mail:<span
                                                    class="required" aria-required="true"> * </span></label>
                                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                                    <input type="email"
                                                        ng-model="organizacoesSelecionada.emailResponsavel"
                                                        class="form-control" id="emailResponsavel" maxlength="100"
                                                        name="emailResponsavel" required> <span
                                                        style="color: red"
                                                        ng-show="submitted && form.emailResponsavel.$error.required">Campo
                                                        E-mail Obrigatório.</span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label col-md-3">ID:<span
                                                    class="required" aria-required="true"> * </span></label>
                                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                                    <input type="text"
                                                        ng-model="organizacoesSelecionada.idEscritorioContabil"
                                                        class="form-control" id="idEscritorioContabil" maxlength="100"
                                                        name="idEscritorioContabil" disabled> <span
                                                        style="color: red"
                                                        ng-show="submitted && form.idEscritorioContabil.$error.required">Campo
                                                        ID Obrigatório.</span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </form>

                </p>
            </div>

            <!-- FIM DIALOG -->


        </section>
        <!-- end widget grid -->
```

Meu .js:

```
angular.module('BoxApp').controller("ResponsavelOrganizacao", function($scope, $http) {

$scope.organizacoes = {};
$scope.organizacoesSelecionada = {};

$scope.iniciar = function() {
    $http.get('http://localhost:8080/boxmlV2/cadresponsavelorganizacao').success(function(response) {
        $scope.organizacoes = response;
    });
};  

$scope.iniciar();

$scope.setSelected = function(selecao){
    $scope.organizacoesSelecionada = selecao;
};

/**
 * Trecho para validar o form ao submeter.
 */
$scope.submitted = false;
$scope.submitForm = function(form) {
    $scope.submitted = true;

    if (form.$valid) {
        $scope.editaResponsavelOrganizacao();
    }
};  

$scope.editaResponsavelOrganizacao = function() {

    var str = telefone.value;
    telefone.value = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '');
    str = celular.value;
    celular.value = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '');

    $http.post('/boxmlV2/cadresponsavelorganizacao/salvar', {
        idEscritorioContabil : idEscritorioContabil.value,
        nomeResponsavel : nomeResponsavel.value,
        telefone : telefone.value,
        celular : celular.value,
        emailResponsavel : emailResponsavel.value
    }).then(function(response) {
        $scope.sucesso();
    }, function(response) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
    });

};

$scope.sucesso = function() {
    $scope.closeMyPopup();
    $scope.iniciar();
    nomeResponsavel.value = "";
    telefone.value = "";
    celular.value = "";
    emailResponsavel.value = "";
};

$scope.closeMyPopup = function() {
    $(myModal_autocomplete).modal('hide');
};

});
```

Tag script da página:

```
/*
    * DIALOG SIMPLE
    */

    // Dialog click
    $('#dialog_link').click(function() {
        $('#dialog_simple').dialog('open');
        return false;

    });

    $('#dialog_simple').dialog({
        autoOpen : false,
        width : 500,
        resizable : false,
        modal : true,
        title : "Cadastro Responsável Organização",
        buttons : [{
            html : "<i class='.btn .btn-xs'></i>&nbsp; Salvar",
            "class" : "btn btn bg-color-blueLight txt-color-white",
            click : function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }, {
            html : "<i class='.btn .btn-xs'></i>&nbsp; Cancelar",
            "class" : "btn bg-color-red txt-color-white",
            click : function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }]
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro...
Só pode ter um `ID` de um valor em uma página.

Como você está trabalhando com vários registros não vai dar certo você ter um `ID` que abra o `modal` para todas as linhas. Terá de usar classe...

No lugar do `ID="dialog_link"` na linha do **EDITAR** coloque assim:

`class="btn btn-info dialog_link"`.

E na função que abre o `modal` troque isso:

`$('#dialog_link').click(function() {`

Por isso

`$('.dialog_link').click(function() {`

---

Para carregar os dados de um único registro no modal terá que levar o `ID` do registro para a função que abre o `modal`.

Então na linha do **EDITAR** coloque o `id="ID_DO_REGISTRO`.

Em `ID_DO_REGISTRO` coloque o `ID` do registro como se faz no **AngularJS** porquê eu não sei.

Daí na função faça:

```
// Dialog Click
$('.dialog_link').click(function() {
    var idRegistro = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#dialog_simple').dialog('open');

    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: pagina.jsp,
       dataType: "JSON",
       data: { id : idRegistro },
       success: function(data){
           $('.campo-nome').val(data.nome_do_campo);
       }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Em **pagina.jsp** você tem que fazer uma busca com o `ID` na tabela e retornar os registros em formato `json`.

Vai por mim. Cola no pai que é sucesso!

Comment: Agora, para você carregar os dados do registro nos campos do formulário dentro do `MODAL` terá que usar `Ajax`.

Comment: Zoom, valeu cara, mas não chama minha função setSelected(x) nem dá erro, isso que não entendo saca.

Comment: Se for `Angular`, eu não manjo. Eu vi que é... `ng-click`... 
Mas no seu escopo do post você disse que o problema era o `modal`.

Comment: hahaha valeu man ! foi !